# Multiple routing policies for Route 53 pointing to LoadBalancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have a Hosted Zone on Route 53.

Have a subdomain pointing to a ALB.

I have a use case where i want to create something similar to Disaster Recovery. I have 2 regions.
One is the primary region second is for DR.

I am planing to have A record with fail over routing policy set up for primary and secondary region's ALB respectively.

I am also trying to figure out if i have a weighted policy set up for primary and secondary region which will attend to 90 and 10 % of traffic.

How will this turn out?
Will i have 90% and 10% to traffic handled by both the region's ALB and in case of failure of the primary region will all the traffic i.e 100% be handled by secondary region?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create these records you can also create a [Route 53 health check](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover.html) that will determine if the endpoint is healthy or not.

In many routing types if there are multiple values in the policies, if one of them fails a health check then DNS will not resolve to the value until the policy is evaluated. Without this health check there is no affect whether its working or not working.

Take a look at the [How Amazon Route 53 chooses records when health checking is configured](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/health-checks-how-route-53-chooses-records.html) page for more information.

Comment: Understood, as i have a same record name www.example.com selecting only weighted routing should suffice , don't have to add extra fail over routing to it.